# How to remove a compiler flag from target property COMPILE_DEFINITIONS?

Tags: cmake

I am using [llvm_update_compile_flags](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake#L5) like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(test VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "testing")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR})
include(AddLLVM)
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
llvm_update_compile_flags(hello)
```

this gives me the `-fno-exceptions` flag in the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property of the target `hello`, see [line 25 in the source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake#L25). However, I would like to remove this flag when compiling. I tried append the following lines after the call to `llvm_update_compile_flags`:

```
get_target_property(_compile_definitions hello COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
list(REMOVE_ITEM _compile_definitions "-fno-exceptions")
set_target_properties(hello PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${_compile_definitions})
```

but when I run `make VERBOSE=1` I can see that it still compiles with `-fno-exceptions`:

```
[...]
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.cpp.o
clang++ -D_compile_definitions-NOTFOUND -I/usr/lib/llvm-13/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS  -fno-exceptions -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.cpp.o -c /home/hakon/test/cmake/hello.cpp
[...]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there were two issues that prevented the option from being removed:

- First, `llvm_update_compile_flags` adds `-fno-exceptions` to property `COMPILE_FLAGS` not `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`, see [line 75](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake#L75)
- Second, `llvm_update_compile_flags` inserts a space in front of the flag, see [line 58](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake#L58)

So the following modification of `CMakeLists.txt` worked as expected:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(test VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "testing")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR})
message(STATUS "LLVM_CMAKE_DIR = ${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")
include(AddLLVM)
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
llvm_update_compile_flags(hello)
get_target_property(_compile_flags hello COMPILE_FLAGS)
list(REMOVE_ITEM _compile_flags " -fno-exceptions")
set_target_properties(hello PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${_compile_flags}")
```